# Compare sum of two field in partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I created a partial view to store the `AC Name`, `AC Code`, `Credit`, and `Debit` fields. So when **Add New Record** button clicks, again another partial view will load.

So What I want to know is, in the end, I want to get the sum of `credit` field values and `debit` fields values and want to show whether the amounts are balanced or not.

This Partial view loads within the `Create` View.

Could I get help here to know how to do that?

This is my partial view code

```
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group"> A/C Name <div class="col-md-10"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ACName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Make it short" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ACName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group"> A/C Code <div class="col-md-10"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ACCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ACCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group"> Debit <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Rs.</span> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Debit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onkeypress = "return RestrictCommaSemicolon(event);" } })
          </div> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Debit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group"> Credit <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Rs.</span> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Credit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onkeypress = "return RestrictCommaSemicolon(event);" } })
          </div> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Credit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is how it looks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simple to do, you just need to get the values from the inputs(credit and debit) by adding an [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with `change` event name, then bind the results in another tag by passing the value by selecting the tag then changing the value by [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution  :

```
          //Assuming that your ajax method to get the partial view is like this.
          $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetMyPartialView", "Home")',
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {data: yourDataIfNecessary},
                ContentType: 'application/json;utf-8',
                success: function (result) {

                    //You append the partial container
                    $("#MyPartialContainer").append(result);

                    //Your new fields are accessible.
                    calculateMyValue();
                },
                error: function (err) {

                }
            });



         function calculateMyValue(){
           //Gets your input which contains the value.
           var myInputs = $(".my-input-by-class-name");

           var summ = 0;
           for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.Length; i++) {
              sum += $(myInputs[i].val());
           }


            $("#my-result-input-by-id").val(summ);
         }
```